# Sending get request using python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Sending get request with query string but `requests` is stripping the query string. I tried encoding it with `urllib.parse.urlencode()` but still the result is same with `requests`. Any help please...

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html'
params = { 
    'checkin_monthday': '19',
    'checkin_year': '2018',
    'checkout_month': '4',
    'checkout_monthday': '20',
    'checkout_year': '2018',
    'class_interval': 1,
    'dest_id': -1022488,
    'dest_type': 'city',
    'dtdisc': 0,
    'from_sf': 1,
    'group_adults': 2,
    'group_children':   0,
    'inac': 0,
    'index_postcard': 0,
    'label': 'gen1',
    'label_click': 'undef',
    'no_rooms': 1,
    'offset': 0,
    'postcard': 0,
    'raw_dest_type': 'city',
    'room1': 'A,A',
    'sb_price_type': 'total',
    'sb_travel_purpose': 'business',
    'src': 'index',
    'src_elem': 'sb',
    'ss': 'Pokhara',
    'ss_all': 0,
    'ssb': 'empty',
    'sshis': 0,
    'ssne': 'Pokhara',
    'ssne_untouched': 'Pokhara',
}

# import urllib
# formatted_query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
# url = url + '?' + formatted_query_string

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(r.url)

# output
# https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?dest_id=-1022488;est_type=city;ss=Pokhara
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Your code is fine, no need to use `urllib`. The reason why you are getting "stripped" URL is that this is not the *initial* URL you're looking for.

#### Explanation

If you examine `requests` [source code](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/?highlight=Final), you can find that `r.url` is

> `Final URL location of Response`

So `r.url` is **not** the URL you requested, this is URL you have been (finally) redirected to. You can make a simple test:

```
from requests import Request, Session


url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html'  # your url

params = {  # I intentionally shortened this dict for testing purposes
    'checkin_monthday': '19',
    'checkin_year': '2018',
    'checkout_monthday': '20',
    'checkout_year': '2018',
}

req = Request('GET', url, params=params)
prepped = req.prepare()
print(prepped.url)  # you send this URL ...

s = Session()
resp = s.send(prepped)
print(resp.url)  # ... but you are redirected to this URL (same as your r.url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?checkin_year=2018&checkin_monthday=19&checkout_monthday=20&checkout_year=2018
https://www.booking.com/
```

What happens here:

1. You python script sends request with all your parameters.
2. Server processes you request and responds with `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`. Redirect location can be found in headers: `Location: https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?dest_id=-1022488;est_type=city;ss=Pokhara`.
3. `requests` receives this response and goes to this location. The location URL is put to `r.url` attribute.

That's why initial URL and final URL are different.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand it clearly now.